# Making an executable jar that evals Clojure strings

Tags: java, maven-2, clojure

I'm building a Java app that loads Clojure files.  I'm having trouble making a single executable jar.  I'm using One-Jar, but I get an exception when I try to run the jar file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ziroby.clojure.App.main(App.java:14)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.RT.lastModified(RT.java:374)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:434)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:316)
... 7 more
```

When I look at the line that's causing it, it seems to be trying to get jar information for the relative class files:

```java
    return ((JarURLConnection) url.openConnection()).getJarFile()
           .getEntry(libfile).getTime();
```

I think this means that it's trying to get jar information for an embedded jar, which doesn't actually exist on the file system.  It's looking at that to see if it needs to recompile a file (like `common/core.clj`).

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there some other way to create an executable jar (with dependencies) without confusing Clojure?

Comment: Wow!  I can see at least 5 things that might fail in that single code statement.  Is it your code, or another API?  BTW the usual solution (as opposed to one-jar) is to either deploy all the Jars using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), or add a manifest that refers to the dependent Jars by relative references, then package them up in an installer of some form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that this is a bug in Clojure.  I am able to add a single null check (just before the `.getTime()` call), and it works correctly.  I've entered a bug in Clojure's Jira: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-971